# MAAS "Failed deployment" on node with 16.04 LTS

Tags: maas

We have a node with commodity hardware (Dell r620). I can successfully deploy Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 15.04.

When I attempt to deploy 16.04 LTS MAAS eventually returned "Failed deployment".

```
INFO    Mon, 18 April 2016 21:30:14 Node changed status — From 'Deploying' to 'Failed deployment'   
INFO    Mon, 18 April 2016 20:56:09 PXE Request — local boot    
INFO    Mon, 18 April 2016 20:54:06 Installation complete — Node disabled netboot   
INFO    Mon, 18 April 2016 20:52:41 PXE Request — curtin install    
INFO    Mon, 18 April 2016 20:52:41 PXE Request — curtin install    
INFO    Mon, 18 April 2016 20:50:18 Node powered on 
INFO    Mon, 18 April 2016 20:50:14 Powering node on
```

I'm unsure how to debug this further.  Any hints as to where to check next?

Edit:
Serial console outputs this:

```
CLIENT MAC ADDR: EC F4 BB CC AD 7C  GUID: 44454C4C 5000 1044 8057 B7C04F503232
CLIENT IP: 10.129.76.2  MASK: 255.255.255.0  DHCP IP: 10.129.49.2
GATEWAY IP: 10.129.76.1
!PXE entry point found (we hope) at 96B2:0106 via plan A
UNDI code segment at 96B2 len 5E00
UNDI data segment at 9072 len 6400
Getting cached packet  01 02 03
My IP address seems to be 0A814C02 10.129.76.2
ip=10.129.76.2:10.129.49.2:10.129.76.1:255.255.255.0
BOOTIF=01-ec-f4-bb-cc-ad-7c
SYSUUID=44454c4c-5000-1044-8057-b7c04f503232
TFTP prefix:
Trying to load: pxelinux.cfg/01-ec-f4-bb-cc-ad-7c                   ok
Booting local disk ...
Booting...
```

The actual video output is nonsense. A bunch of weird symbols.  I'll have to take a picture of it and attache it but I don't think it'll be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would take a look at the screen (display/SOL/IPKVM) of the machine being deployed. I bet you will see some interesting info there.

You can also change Ubuntu version used for commissioning to 16.04, recommission your machine with option "Allow SSH access and prevent from powering off" checked. That will give you a chance to look at the situation with your machine and Ubuntu 16.04 "from inside".

Comment: I updated the question with more info. I'm seeing strange symbols after the pxe boot.  No useful debug information that I can see